# Outlook Mail Graph API polling parameter combination using top and isRead ne true, returns wrong result

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

The API seems to have a fault. I'm getting 10 unread mails like this;

GET /v1.0/me/mailFolders/xxx/messages?$filter=isRead%20ne%20true&$count=true&$top=10

But it seems that the backend is actually taking top 10 of ALL emails in the folder, and then getting the unread from that 10 mails. So, if the first 10 emails are not unread, the result is 0 mails found, even though the folder have perhaps 25 unread mails.

So the result depends on the order of the mails in the folder and result can vary between 0 found and all 10 (and thereby all 25 in succeeding polls).

My questions is, if there is a way to alter my query to get what I need, or if this issue should be brought to Microsoft's attention?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this way `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false & $count=true & $top=10` and I am able to get the total count having isread as false and the top 10 having isread as false. Even the ones which are isread equals true are there in my inbox, it gave me the right results. So I was unable to reproduce the issue using POSTMAN. Please try it with POSTMAN or [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge).

Comment: Yes, I have tested this with Graph Explorer and my own inbox and I cannot reproduce it either. A customer has reported this and another person sort of experienced the same. So for sure it does not occur always. Hard to report something that you cannot reproduce consistently... :(

Comment: Could you please get the requestid and timestamp for those type of inaccurate data response?